# How can I show embedded images in HTML e-mails sent from my website in Hotmail?

Tags: email

When I send HTML e-mails from my website with my logo as an embedded image, Hotmail hides it by default with the message `Attachments, pictures and links in this message have been blocked for your safety.`

Since this is my logo, it makes the e-mail look very funny.  Is there some certification/verification process to allow embedded images from my domain to be shown by default in Hotmail and other major e-mail service providers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, no there is no certification program. All major web email clients do this and there is no way around it.

Comment: Gmail always _displays_ attached (ie. embedded) images - but as an attachment, after the message. External images are blocked by default. In fact, so does Hotmail.

Comment: @w3d yes, while thats true it doesn't answer the question asked or help patrick.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the logo on your website and use the `<img>` tag to display the image in your email. Email clients like Outlook and Gmail ask the user if they want to display the images.

Comment: I tried that, but users are still prompted to choose whether they would like to display the image or not.  Since it's just my logo, I don't want to inconvenience users by making them click to display it; if I can't display it automatically, I'll just use text instead.

Comment: He's running into the security blocks in gmail and hotmail that prevent images loading unless the user ascents to their display - there is no way around it, it doesn't matter where you serve the content from.